# Related terms View based on current node (Drupal)

Tags: drupal

When visiting node/x, how to use this node's taxonomy term's related terms as argument, and then get a related terms View?

Say, node/123 has a vocabulary "Country" and its term is Canada. Within the same vocabulary, "Canada" is related term of "USA" and "Mexico". Then I want to get a related terms View that list nodes associated with terms USA and Mexico as well.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track. What problem are you running into?

Comment: I don't know how to so create such Views. Downloaded a module (Similar By Terms) and it can partially does what I want (It considers that if a node is associated with at least one of terms used in another node, that the former node is a "related" of the later. But I still need a way to show nodes that associated with "Related Terms", which I manually set via terms edit page.

Answer (score 0):

**talking D7 ..**

i would suggest to make a new view, with a block display,
where you give the taxonomy-id as contextual-filter. make sure to check the relations options ..

then make a custom block (php) and call it like:

```
<?php $view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->set_arguments(array($YOUR_TERM_ID));
$view->set_display('block_display_name');
print $view->preview('block_display_name'); ?>
```

a views-generated block did not work for me ...

Comment: I will try. I think I first need to get tid(s) based on nid and vid, and then get nids based on tid.

Comment: use **entity_load** to load a node, with a nid, taken from url or already set 8depending on where you are, then parse the result and you got your tid

Comment: Thanks. But I am using D6 at this time.